# Flat map with reduced fibers.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Hi.

Let $f:X\rightarrow S$ be a flat, surjective morphism of complex spaces with reduced fibers over $S$ reduced. 
Q1: Is $X$ reduced too?

Q2: Is the property " reduced fiber" preserved by base change given by the normalization?

Rk: 1) We have some result of this kind in [EGA4], Cor (3.3.5) p.44.

2) We can apply [Matsumara], Cor(ii) p.189 but with the additional asumptions: $S$ is normal and $X$ locally pure dimensional.

Thanks.

Comment: For algebraic varieties over an algebraically closed fields, Q1 follows from EGA IV, Théorème 9.7.7 (the set of $s\in S$ such that $X_s$ is geometrically reduced is locally constructible in $S$) and the Corollaire you cited (which is also the Theorem in Matsumura as pointed out by Angelo). 

For Q2, if you ask whether $X\times_S S'\to S'$ has reduced fibers for any morphism $S'\to S$, then the answer is clearly yes because the original fibers are geometrically reduced.

Answer (score 6):

Dear kaddar, here is a partial answer.

According to a theorem of Douady, a  flat map $f:X\to S$ between complex analytic spaces is always open . So if you assume that the fibers of $f$ are reduced *and* that your reduced space $S$ is actually smooth (i.e. is a manifold), then $X$ is indeed reduced : this follows from the Proposition on page 158 of Gerd Fischer's *Complex Analytic Geometry* 
(Springer, LNM 538, 1976).

**Edit**  $\;$ On the evoked relation between flat and open, let me add the following. It is *not* true that an open morphism $f:X\to S$ of complex spaces is flat: the simplest counter-example is the immersion of a simple point into a double point i.e.  the morphism of schemes $Spec \;\mathbb C \to Spec \; \mathbb C[\epsilon ] \quad(\epsilon^2=0)$  seen analytically.
However if $X$ and $S$ are complex manifolds then it *is* true that $f$ open implies $f$ flat (Fischer, same page 158)
and so for morphisms between manifolds you have the easy to remember equivalence flat=open, which helps  understand the notoriously unintuitive notion of flatness.

Answer (score 4):

This is a consequence of the following result: if $A \to B$ is a flat local homomorphism of local rings, $A$ and $B/\mathfrak{m}_AB$ are reduced, then $B$ is reduced. Keeping in mind that reduced is equivalent to $R_0$ and $S_1$, this follows from Theorem 23.9 in Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory.

I don't know what the second question means.

[Edit] I just noticed that the hypotheses in the cited theorem are actually stronger, so that it would imply the result for schemes but not for analytic spaces, at least not immediately. I need to think about it some more.

Comment: Dear Georges,

Thank you for the partial answer (I found another reference for this (with smooth base) :satz 2.4 p.245 in "Deformation komplexer Raume "of  Grauert-Kerner in Math.Ann 153).

Can we deduce from the case of smooth base the general case by considering the base change given by the natural injection of the smooth part $Reg(S)$ in $S$ . We must then show that the fiber product of $X$ by $Reg(S)$ over $S$ is an open, dense and reduced  subspace of $X$. I think that density is due to the flatness which preserve schematic density and reducedness is due to smooth base case....





Comment: Thanks to Liu and Angelo for the good reference in EGA and Matsumara  commutative algebra. 
Dear Angelo, in the second question, i want to know if a morphism with reduced fibers stay with reduced fibers after any base change $S'\rightarrow S$ between reduced complex spaces ? 

Liu say that the answer is yes because the notion of "geometrically reduced " and "reduced" agree in complex analytic geometric.

Comment: It seems to me that the result is valid for $f:X\rightarrow S$ assumed to be open (or universally open in AG). For see this, we can argue as above on $Reg(S)$ by base change...

Comment: Is the result realy true for open morphism?