# is tensor square of a reduced ring reduced?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a reduced algebra of finite type over a field $k$ of characteristic 0. Let $S$ be a reduced finite $R$-algebra. Is $S \otimes_R S$ reduced?

(In positive characteristic one can get non-reduced tensor products of reduced algebras even over a field.)

I have failed to find a counterexample so I thought that the statement might be true after all. The question is motivated by the discussion in the comments to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88108/reduction-of-a-module).

If $S=R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I$, what one has to show is that the ideal $I \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes I$ in $S \otimes_R S=R[x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n]$ is radical. However, I have no good ideas as to how to approach this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Let $R = k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$. Let $S = k[t]$, with the map $R \to S$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto (t^2, t^3)$. So $S \otimes_R S = k[t,u]/(t^2-u^2, t^3-u^3)$. The element $t-u$ is not zero in the tensor product, because all the relations are in degree $>1$. But $(t-u)^3 = 3 (t-u)(t^2-u^2) - 2 (t^3-u^3)$ is in the ideal.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder if it is a coincidence that this counterexample is not flat.

Comment: Dear David, is it possible to turn this counterexample into a counterexample where S is of the form $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ where I is generated by elements linear in $x_i$-s? E.g. applying the functor $Sym$ to $S$ (seen as a finite module over $R$) we get $R[u,v]/(ux−vy)$. However, I can't easily see if $R[u,v,t,s]/(ux−vy,tx−sy)$ is reduced or not.

Comment: That's reduced. The ideal has primary decomposition $(ux-vy, tx-sy,us-tv) \cap (x,y)$, and each of those are prime. I don't see any fundamental reason something like this couldn't work, though.  

Comment: I think I see why this can't work. For any point $\mathrm{Spec}(K) \in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$, if the equations are of the form you describe, then the fiber of $\mathrm{Spec}(S)$ over $\mathrm{Spec}(K)$ is a linear space. So the fiber of $\mathrm{Spec}(S \otimes_R S)$ over $\mathrm{Spec}(K)$ is the square of that linear space, and is hence reduced. There should be a theorem that, if $Y$ is reduced, and every fiber of $X \to Y$ is reduced, then $X$ is reduced. I don't know a citation for that, though.

Comment: This is nice. Concerning the theorem that you mention, is $Y$ over a field or is it a general scheme?

Comment: OK, the result I hoped for above isn't true. $\mathrm{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$ including into $\mathrm{Spec} k[x,y]$. Not sure which way I want to guess about your result.

Comment: If $S$ is flat over $R$, then the result I want works; see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51004/flat-map-with-reduced-fibers

Comment: Sorry, for which statement does $k[x,y] \to k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$ serve as a counterexample? Surely not for the "reducedness of fibres implies reducedness of the top scheme"

Comment: If $S$  is flat over $R$ then the dimension of the fibres is constant.

Comment: All fibers of $\mathrm{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy,y^2) \to mathrm{Spec} k[x,y]$ are points or empty (hence reduced). The target is reduced, yet the source is not. (Obviously, I was over thinking this. $\mathrm{Spec} k[x]/x^2 \to \mathrm{Spec} k[x]$ works just as well.) Yes, I know that flat implies constant fiber dimension. But I don't think it is obvious  that flat plus all fibers reduced over reduced base implies reduced -- which is why I cited the MO answer where this is shown.

Comment: You are right about the example, of course. I am grateful for the reference about flat morphism and reducedness, all I meant was that this theorem cannot be used to explain that $R[u,v,t,s]/(ux−vy,tx−sy)$ and similar examples are reduced. 

Comment: I don't get it. In the original question, $R$ is assumed finite over $k$. David's example is not.

Comment: Dear Laurent, my fault, I should have said "finite type".